# Looking for a correct .htaccess rewrite for IIRF.ini (IIS6)

Tags: iis, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, ini

I'm having some trouble with a windows hosting.
We're working with PHP and need an mod_rewrite.

Yet windows does not support .htaccess.
We do have IIRF.

Can someone help me with translating this .htaccess into a working IIRF.ini file?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /new/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /new/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Would rock.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f<br>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d<br>
RewriteRule /. /new/index.php [L,QSA]
```

it worked for me with Windows Server 2003, IIS 6, IIRF 2.1 and Wordpress 3.8.